# Normalized Tables in MVC with Concurrency Checking (ACID)

Tags: database, model-view-controller, architecture, concurrency, normalization

Two part question:

**Number 1**: What is the best approach in creating a model for an object that references another object, when some of the properties/attributes of the referenced object are not always necessary?

Imagine if you have two objects: **PERSON** and **BUSINESS**

```
Person
+ PersonID
+ Name
+ Age
+ Sex
+ Skill
+ Business *

Business
+ BusinessID
+ Name
+ Address
+ CorporateVision (this is large)
```

In the example above: A **PERSON** has a reference to a **BUSINESS** as their current employer.

In the database, I would have two tables for each object.  While in code, using the MVC architecture pattern, I would have two classes for each object.   The database would have a foreign-key relationship between **BUSINESS**-->**PERSON**, while in code the **PERSON** object would have a member variable that holds a reference to a **BUSINESS** object.

Now let's say I want to enumerate on a collection of **PERSONS** and find out the total number of those that work for a specific company (based on **BUSINESS** . **Name**).

Without using MVC, I could just create a function that would query the database and get a count.  Simple and efficent.

WITH MVC, I need to instantiate every **PERSON** object, which in turns, instantiates a **BUSINESS** object for the reference (if one was not already done for it... the **BusinessFactory** would check a collection first).  Furthermore, it MUST pull in **BUSINESS** . **CorporateVision** from the database for every object.  And because most of these businesses are Media Marketing Companies, most of their corporate visions are large text blobs.  So it is very unnecessary to read CorporateVision from the database when all we need is the name of the business.

I could solve this problem by having changing the **PERSON** object in code to:

```
Person
+ PersonID
+ Name
+ Age
+ Sex
+ Skill
+ BusinessID
+ BusinessName
```

So now when I create my **PERSON** object, I do a JOIN with **BUSINESS** and cache the name.  Now I can get the BusinessName quickly and efficiently... and I still can get the full **BUSINESS** object as needed by doing a lookup on the ID.  But I just denormalized the model... and I just introduced a new problem... and a new question.

**Number 2**: How does MVC handle concurrency with a multi-user database?

Lets say while my client application is enumerating (using the enumeration that I mentioned above that finds all people that work for a particular business), another user merged two of the **BUSINESS** objects.

Now my in-memory collection is wrong because all of the BusinessName caching is stale.  The same could be true if I had just left the **PERSON** . **Business** as a **BUSINESS** object reference: The **BUSINESS** object would be stale.

**In summary**: I feel that with MVC I lose data retrieval efficiency as well as the loss of the ACIDness of my application.  Or am I using MVC wrong?

Comment: I think I may have found an answer: [Object-relational impedance mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix UI and Data access, while you should minimize their dependencies over another. MVC is actually a pretty broad pattern which describes how application interacts with user. Both your questions are related to data access.

1) MVC is the way you organize UI. So, model is a piece of information you want to make user interact with. Note, business objects are not priority here. If there is a case when use loads a `Person` class along with several properties from `Business`, so be it: your second Person rendition is a perfect model for this case. And so on - each use case requires a different model and you should create different model for different scenarios.

If you think it's easier for you to call a function to calculate the number - fine. Remember, you are not bound to business objects here.

With more 'object'-oriented approach we usually solve this reference problem in two ways:

- first is lazy loading, with is out-of-the-box feature for modern O/RMs. So you load a person and after a first call to Person.Business, latter is loaded automatically.
- second is that you create a special kind UI, which is aware of your data access specifics and either has only fields you use, or requests additional data in an async manner from a client.

2) Again, MVC doesn't handles concurrency, and it shouldn't handle it and shouldn't even bother. It's a concern of data access layer. And there are also several ways to deal with concurrency, major of them are optimistic and pessimistic locks. (With the first one you allow different users to make conflicting changes and try to resolve conflicts when they  occur. The second way prevents conflicts by locking updates completely). Again, O/RMs deal with it usually; or you can use your own implementation, but it should be still data access, not MVC part.